# Postgres executable for standalone mode in Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql

I installed Postgres 9.5 on Ubuntu 16.10 a while ago, following instructions [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-16-04).

I need to run Postgres in standalone mode for a database vacuum. I need to run this command:

```
postgres --single -D /full/path/to/datadir postgres
```

But the `postgres` command is not available:

```
$ postgres
No command 'postgres' found, did you mean:
 Command 'postgrey' from package 'postgrey' (universe)
postgres: command not found
```

Its not available in the `postgres` user path either:

```
dbuser@pgserver:~$ sudo -i
root@pgserver:~# su postgres
postgres@pgserver:/root$ postgres
No command 'postgres' found, did you mean:
 Command 'postgrey' from package 'postgrey' (universe)
postgres: command not found
```

Where is this utility, or what do I need to install to have access to it?

Answer (score 2):

The `postgres` command (as well as `pg_ctl` and others) are in `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin`.

Notably, they have to be run by a non-privileged user like `postgres`. Here's what I did to resolve my issue:

1. Make home directory for postgres user:

   ```
   $ sudo -i
   $ mkdir /home/postgres
   $ chown postgres:postgres /home/postgres
   $ usermod -d /home/postgres/ postgres
   ```
2. Edit the PATH:

   ```
   $ su - postgres
   $ vim ~/.bash_profile
   ```

   Append:

   ```
   PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin
   export PATH
   ```
3. Run `su - postgres` to access the commands:

   ```
   $ postgres --single -D /full/path/to/datadir postgres
   PostgreSQL stand-alone backend 9.5.7
   backend>
   ```